# Jquery redirect and ajax execution sequence

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a function on a form submit, it executes everything but an ajax request. I do some checks before sending the data, but in the part where I check the checked state of the checkbox, I have a problem, when it is true it redirects to the URL that I specified, and with that the ajax `success` never does nothing, actually the data is never sent to the Ajax URL. When checked is false the data is sent to the URL specified inside the ajax method (my ajax function is `save_sell`).

And if I put the redirection code inside Ajax, the redirection never happens.

```
$('#my_form').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($('#select1').val()===''){
              alert('Message 1');
            }
            else if ($('#select2').val()===''){
              alert('Message2');
            }
            else if ($('#select3').val()===''){
              alert('Message3');
            }
            else if ($('#select4').val()===''){
              alert('Message4');
            }
            else if ($('#numperinput1').val()==='0.00' || $('#numberinput1').val()==='' ){
              alert('Message5');
            }
            else if ($('#select5').val()===''){
              alert('Message6');
            }
            else {
              console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
              var tbl = $('table#My_table tr').get().map(function(row) {
                return $(row).find('td').get().map(function(cell) {
                  return $(cell).html();
                });
              });
              $.each(tbl, function(key,value) {
                value.pop();
              });
              tbl.shift();
              var tblJson=JSON.stringify(tbl);
              save_sell(tblJson);
              console.log("saving");

              if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) { //here is the problem
                $(location).attr('href', '/the_url?number=5');
                console.log("downloading");
              }
              console.log("after download");
            }
        });
```

EDIT: Here is my ajax function

```
        function save_sell(table_array) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "/Store/Sell/", 
                type : "POST",
                data : { table: table_array},
                success : function(json) {
                  console.log('Success!');
                  var res_sell=json.idsell;
                  console.log('Sell:'+res_idsell);
                  $("#sell_result").text(res_idsell);
                },

                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! Error: "+errmsg+
                        " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>");
                    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        };
```

Is there a solution to send data through ajax and wait for ajax response before doing a redirect?

---

EDIT: I tried to add this, just wrote it on the script:

```
    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) { 
      if ( settings.url === "/Store/Sell/" ) { 
        console.log("Ajax complete");
        if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
          console.log("Checked");
          $(location).attr('href', '/the_url?number=5');
        }
      }
    });
```

I can see the "Ajax complete" in the console, but the "Checked" is never written in the console.

I also tried to append this to the end of my ajax:

```
            function save_sell(table_array) {
                $.ajax({
                       //all the ajax thing that I posted before
                }).done(function( data ) {
                        console.log("Ajax complete");
                        if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
                               console.log("Checked");
                        $(location).attr('href', '/the_url?number=5');
                        }
                });
           };
```

And had the same results, I can see the "Ajax complete" in the console, but the "Checked" isn't never written in the console.

Comment: Tried the `complete()` function in the AJAX?

Comment: @Scott Actually no, I'm going to edit my question and post my ajax function, so you can tell where I must put it :D

Answer (score 1):

Following this conversation:
[How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

you should use `$('#checkbox1').checked` to test the value of a checkbox.

The flow of ajax call is as follows:

```
beforeAjax();
$.ajax(...).done(function(){
     afterReceivingWithSuccess();
 }).complete(function(){
     afterReceiving();
 });
 afterSendingAjaxCall();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using AJAX after that redirect page, Ajay is running under asynchronous and not stop further execution . So prevent and wait for AJAX you have to pass `async: false` in ajax parameter you have to redirect from AJAX success callback function

Answer (score 0):

Now is working with the appended "done" in the ajax method, it was my error, at the end of the submit I had this code:

```
$('#my_form').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

With that code checkbox1 was always false, I changed my code to this:

```
$('#my_form').find(':checkbox').not('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);
```

And changed it to false just after entering to the "if" inside the "done" of the ajax method.